# Why can't I store timeIntervalSince1970 return value to a pointer?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I'm a beginner (at programming) learning Objective-C. Xcode will not let me allocate a return value from an NSDate object; I am confused by this.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
long seconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
```

If I use a pointer to store the seconds:

```
long *seconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
```

I see the error:

> Initializing 'long *' with an expression of incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')

Why can't I say "Give me the return value of `now.timeIntervalSince1970` and stick at this address"?

Another question is, why can't I initialize an object and use it without needing a pointer? This will not work.

```
NSDate dateObject = [NSDate date];
```

I realize my question probably has a very easy answer, but the book doesn't explain any of the "why does it work this way" questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]` returns the value as an `NSTimeInterval` which is a `typedef`d `double`, which is a primitive type, not an object type.

The value counts the number of seconds since 1-Jan-1970, and does not need to be an object.

You *could* store it in a pointer, but that would be silly:

```
NSTimeInterval *elapsed = (NSTimeInterval *)malloc(sizeof(NSTimeInterval));
*elapsed = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
...
free(elapsed);
```

Comment: Thanks. First I've heard of `primitive` types and `object` types. I'll hazard a guess that object's receive messages while primitive types don't? So we use pointers to store addresses of objects?

Comment: I guess I'm confused because the book started with C. And now it seems the rules are changing for Objective-C without the book saying why.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton Well it's a big subject that you *must* look into, however objects are all built out of primitives, and those objects must be allocated dynamically (similar the `malloc()` code I show) and yes objects receive messages.

Answer (score 1):

`timeIntervalSince1970` returns an `NSTimeInterval` which is a type def of `double`. In the Apple documentation you will see this defined like

**objective-c**

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

**Swift**

```
typealias NSTimeInterval = Double
```

and double is a primitive and not an object type so shouldn't be a pointer (Shouldn't is in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1)). The Apple documentation also states the below

> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.

Here is the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTimeInterval)

Comment: "double is a primitive and not an object type so can't be a pointer" ... you can have a pointer to a primitive type, which is exactly what the asker is asking how to do in this case.

Comment: @nhgrif Ok maybe I should rephrase that to you shouldn't which **is** in the Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1 as a side note whilst looking for the documentation I did see loads of answers on here that state **can't** which have loads of upvotes.

Comment: "Can't" is wrong.  "Shouldn't" is questionable as to whether or not it is wrong.  If you **shouldn't** point to primitive data-types, why does C (non-OOP language) have pointers?  How would primitive arrays work?

Comment: @nhgrif this is what's throwing me off. The book starts off with C. And it has just moved to Objective-C. The author never bothered to mention that in Objective-C you can't do `Int *i = 10` which worked in C.

Comment: @nhgrif totally agree it is questionable not going to argue with you about that, but it has it in the docs so that makes me slightly happy

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton Sorry you cannot do `int *i = 10;` in C and expect the code not to crash.